# How to properly open a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a problem that will be very simple to solve but I don't know how to do it.

Scenario: I want to run an emulator coded in C++ by a YT (javidx9) in Visual Studio. The project is here: https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcNES and the folder is "Part#2 - CPU"

Problem: I never use Visual Studio, so its something new for me, and my problem is that I don't know how to run the project (emulator). And I can't find any post or article on the internet about my problem. (I tried to create an empty project in VS and then copy the emulator files to the folder of my empty project and then run it, but it sent me an error that the files were not found (and its because that isn't the correct way to run the program and I don't know how to do it)).

My request: I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me how to open and run this project (the emulator) correctly in Visual Studio.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your project does not have. sln file. You need to create new project in visual studio.  Last file has main function as below. You need to run this main file(olcNes_Video1_6502.cpp)
You may need to check path of headers included from other projects.

Comment: I create an empty project where I have the .sln file, I also saw that I needed to include the olcPixelGameEngine library, but it keeps giving the same error. I did not understand the last part you mentioned, about the int main().

Comment: It seems that you need to improt [oclPixelGameEngine](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine).

Comment: I imported the library, but it still gives an error....

Comment: If you could provide error information, it will help solve the problem.

Comment: Well... its in spanish:
Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error LNK2019 símbolo externo _main sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) Last C:\Users\davic\source\repos\Last\Last\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) 1

Comment: I sugggest that you could try to set `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)` in `Properties->Linker->System->SubSystem`.